# The total amount Edgar paid for a slice of pizza and a tip of exactly $24\%$ was between $\$2.50$ and $\$3.00$. What was the price of the pizza slice?

Tags: contest-math, percentages

> The total amount Edgar paid for a slice of pizza and a tip of exactly 24% was between $\$2.50$ and $\$3.00$. What was the price of the pizza slice?

Well, I did the trial and error method and managed to get $\$2.25$, but I feel like there'd be a more mathematical way to solve this. For example, if the price was $x$, then I could try solving it as $2.5 < 1.24 x < 3$, but that doesn't necessarily make the problem easier, I think. And above all, it may be easier if I could use a calculator for this question, but I'm not allowed to, so I'd like to find a way to solve this without a calculator...

Uh, just to avoid confusion, there wasn't any limit, but how I understand the problem is that 1.24x (the x here is the same variable I used above)should terminate right at the hundredth digit...?

Comment: The inequality $2.5<1.24x<3$ is correct. This gives that $(2.5/1.24)<x<(3/1.24)$ but I do not think that there is a way to solve this without calculator. Moreover you will find an interval for possible values for $x$, not an exact solution.

Comment: @JimmyR Perhaps there should be a condition that you could only pay with a certain currency,

Comment: @MorganRodgers That helps me, Thanks!

Comment: @JimmyR.: I just solved it in my head, in about 30 seconds. So you mean [this kind of calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_calculator), right?

Comment: 24% tip on a slice of pizza? Only happens in the USA.

Comment: @TonyK Hahahaha, I admit I did not think about this option...

Answer (score 1):

Well, note that $2.5=\frac{5}{2}$, and that $1.24=\frac{31}{25}$.

Dividing the two gives us that $x>\frac{125}{62}$, and in the same method we earn $x<\frac{75}{31}$.

The decimal expression for each is $2.01612\dots$, and $2.419354 \dots $.

If you could only pay the original money with cents, the values would be $2.02$,$2.03$, $\dots$ $2.41$ dollars.

If you could pay with dimes, the values would be $2.1$, $2.2$, $2.3$, $2.4$ dollars.

If you could pay with quarters, the only value would be $2.25$ dollars.

But in order for the tip $0.24x=\frac{6x}{25}$ to be an integer, then $x$ needs to be divisible by $25$, so you have to pay with quarters.

Comment: +1. But please replace 61 by 62, and correct the ensuing numerical values.

Comment: @Did Correct now?

Comment: Yes. // If the price and the tip must both be an integer number of cents the result is unique... Dunno.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers Is you have stated, fractional cents to not exist, and assuming alternate currencies could also cause such problems. and why does $2.79 not work? It is between 2.5 and 3 dollars.

Answer (score 0):

> The total amount Edgar paid for a slice of pizza and a tip of exactly 24% was between $\$2.50$ and $\$3.00$. What was the price of the pizza slice?

This models as
\begin{align}
2.5 \le & \,\, p + 0.24 \, p \le 3 \iff \\
2.5 \le & \,\, 1.24 \,p \le 3 \iff \\
2.01 \le \frac{2.5}{1.24} \le & \,\, p \le \frac{3}{1.24} \le 2.42
\end{align}
where $p$ is the price of the slice of pizza. Used was that one can divide both sides of an inequality with a positive number, which does not change the ordering, the less than operator stays.

> And above all, it may be easier if I could use a calculator for this
>   question, but I'm not allowed to, so I'd like to find a way to solve
>   this without a calculator...

The only calculations are the divisions.
We can write
$$
\frac{2.5}{1.24} = \frac{250}{124} = \frac{125}{62}
$$
to reduce the fractional numbers to a plain fraction of integers.
Then the usual division algorithms for manual calculation apply, e.g after [Adam Riese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ries).

Similar
$$
\frac{3}{1.24} = \frac{300}{124} = \frac{150}{62} 
= \frac{75}{31}
$$